# How do I use a relative path in a Python module when the CWD has changed?

Tags: python, relative-path, python-packaging

I have a Python module which uses some resources in a subdirectory of the module directory.  After searching around on stack overflow and finding related answers, I managed to direct the module to the resources by using something like

```
import os
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'fonts/myfont.ttf')
```

This works fine when I call the module from elsewhere, but it breaks when I call the module after changing the current working directory.  The problem is that the contents of `__file__` are a relative path, which doesn't take into account the fact that I changed the directory:

```
>>> mymodule.__file__
'mymodule/__init__.pyc'
>>> os.chdir('..')
>>> mymodule.__file__
'mymodule/__init__.pyc'
```

How can I encode the absolute path in `__file__`, or barring that, how can I access my resources in the module no matter what the current working directory is?  Thanks!

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Store the absolute path to the module directory at the very beginning of the module:

```
package_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

Afterwards, load your resources based on this `package_directory`:

```
font_file = os.path.join(package_directory, 'fonts', 'myfont.ttf')
```

And after all, do not modify of process-wide resources like the current working directory.  There is never a real need to change the working directory in a well-written program, consequently avoid `os.chdir()`.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly!  I'll also keep your remark in mind to avoid changing the working directory.

Comment: I know this is an old question but somehow it popped up again. -- This is bad practice, and may break in many different scenarios. Use [`pkgutil.get_data()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.get_data) instead.

Comment: @sinoroc Could you please elaborate why you consider this bad practice and give an example of when is might break?

Comment: @pfabri Sometimes things are imported directly from a zip archive, so `__file__` will not have a meaningful/usable value. There is some info about it all around, I don't have one specific reference to give you. But maybe read this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028000/how-to-read-a-static-file-from-inside-a-python-package

Answer (score 2):

Building on [lunaryorn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4187345/5698098), I keep a function at the top of my modules in which I have to build multiple paths. This saves me repeated typing of `join`s.

```py
def package_path(*paths, package_directory=os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))):
    return os.path.join(package_directory, *paths)
```

To build the path, call it like this:

```py
font_file = package_path('fonts', 'myfont.ttf')
```

Or if you just need the package directory:

```py
package_directory = package_path()
```

Comment: This is bad practice, and may break in many different scenarios. Use [`pkgutil.get_data()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.get_data) instead.