# Python absolute path with __file__ for a module called different ways

Tags: python

In my app I have a setup python script (/root/ha/setup.py) which looks through a directory called modules and runs setup.py in each of the subdirectories.

The relevant code is this:

```
""" Exec the module's own setup file """
if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(root, module, "setup.py")):
    execfile(os.path.join(root, module, "setup.py"))
```

The thing is I want /root/ha/modules/modulename/setup.py to work no matter where it's called from.

If I am in modules/modulename and run python setup.py it's fine but if I run it from the directory above modules/ i get this error

```
idFile = open(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "/id.txt", "r").read()
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/ha/id.txt'
```

as you can see it is getting the path of the script that is calling it instead of the script that is running. It should be trying to read /root/ha/modules/modulename/id.txt

I've tried using different methods to get the path but all end up with this error...

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian The questions seems to be about any random setup.py, so he hasn't control over whatever method is used to get file path

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian What I'm saying is that the question is about "How to trick a script that uses `__file__` with execfile".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`execfile` does not modify the globals (as `__file__`) so the exectued script will indeed take an incorrect path.

You can pass global variables to `execfile` so you can modify its `__file__` variable:

```
script = os.path.join(root, module, "setup.py")
if os.path.isfile(script):
    g = globals().copy()
    g['__file__'] = script
    execfile(script, g)
```

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian A "please" wouldn't have gone amiss in that comment. No need to be rude

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is to access a file from some of your packages, then consider using `pkg_resources` as documented here: http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/pkg_resources.html#basic-resource-access

Example of getting content of a file stored as part of package named `package` is in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20885799/346478)