# Accessing static files included in a Python module

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-module

I'm installing my module with pip.  The following is the setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

with open('requirements.txt') as f:
    required = f.read().splitlines()

print(required)
setup(
    name='glm_plotter',
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=required
)
```

and MANIFEST.in:

```
recursive-include glm_plotter/templates *
recursive-include glm_plotter/static *
```

When installing, the directories and files seem to get installed:

```
  ...
  creating build/lib/glm_plotter/templates
  copying glm_plotter/templates/index.html -> build/lib/glm_plotter/templates
...
  creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/glm_plotter/templates
  copying build/lib/glm_plotter/templates/index.html -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/glm_plotter/templates
 ...
```

When I go to import this module:

```
>>> import g_plotter
>>> dir(g_plotter)
['CORS', 'Flask', 'GLMparser', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'app', 'controllers', 'views']
```

I'm not seeing the static files.  I'm not sure if this is the correct way to go about getting access to the static files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read a (static) file from inside a Python package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028000/how-to-read-a-static-file-from-inside-a-python-package)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+package+static+files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dir()` won't tell you anything about static files.  The correct way (or one of them, at least) to get access to this data is with the [`resource_*`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#basic-resource-access) functions in `pkg_resources` (part of setuptools), e.g.:

```
import pkg_resources

pkg_resource.resource_listdir('glm_plotter', 'templates')
# Returns a list of files in glm_plotter/templates

pkg_resource.resource_string('glm_plotter', 'templates/index.html')
# Returns the contents of glm_plotter/templates/index.html as a byte string
```