# Writing Python pip-able package: How to access files in the package?

Tags: python, pip, cefpython

I'm trying to develop a visualization package based on CEFpython technology, so the function has to access an html file. So the structure of the package is basically:

viz_tool

--> **init**.py

--> main.py

--> index.html

and in the main.py file, I defined a function:

```
def view():
    index_filepath = os.path.realpath("index.html")
    print(index_filepath)
    browser = cef.CreateBrowserSync(url='file://' + index_filepath,
                                window_title="viz tool")
    ....
```

The goal is, after installing this package, I can do:

```
from viz_tool import view
view()
```

but of course currently the "index_filepath" would be my current working directory, so it won't be able to find the "index.html" file.

How should I change the code so I could access the "index.html" file, which presumably would be in the directory where the package is installed?

Thank you very much! and please let me know if I need to clarify anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the documentation of `pkg_resources`.
It has a method called `resource_filename` that you can use to get absolute path to any internal module.

```py
from pkg_resources import resource_filename
from foo.bar import bazz # say bazz has template folder

pth_to_template = resource_filename(bazz.__name__, "template")
```

This will return the absolute path to `<path to foo>/foo/bar/bazz/template`.

I would highly recommend not putting html file in root folder and also avoid using hardcoded paths in any form, including doing `os.path.join` recursively to traverse multiple levels. It makes moving files in future a mess.

Edit:
For accessing resources from the same module by relative path, you can do

```py
pth = resource_filename(__name__, "templates/something.html")
```

Edit 2:. 
You will also have to add all the non-python files in package_data as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29071634/9504749) in order for setup.py to add them to the distribution package.

Comment: it seems in this way I need to change the code when loading the view function. is there a way to change the function itself to get the same result?
also, in this case, what would you recommend if I don't put the html in the package? where else should I put it?

Comment: just add a directory names templates. That's what frameworks like Django do.

Comment: @lxiangyun93 I guess you should have a folder for this kind of static file (just not directly the file in the root folder of the package), see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848030/how-include-static-files-to-setuptools-python-package or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53233670/accessing-static-files-included-in-a-python-module if needed to include these files when distributing the package.

Comment: Yes, that too... I guess I misunderstood your question as to how to access the data files, based on the other answer that suggested using `os.path.join` and `__file__`. Yes, for any non python file, you will have ti add it as a data file too

Comment: @dumbPy Thanks a lot! it worked! Would you mind changing the main answer to the one you suggested in the comment, so I could accept the answer?

Comment: @lxiangyun93 Added to answer as requested.