# Extract folder from python package resource

Tags: python, file, package

In my local version of a package I am trying to distribute, I have the following code:

```
shutil.copytree(WWW_LOCATION, dir_path)
```

`WWW_LOCATION` is a subfolder of my python module containing some static files and folders:

```
dv
  \dv
     mytool.py
     \www_folder
       \somefolders_and_files
  setup.py
  MANIFEST.in
  README.md
  LICENSE
  setup.cfg
```

In my code, after execution, I need to copy this whole folder to a user-specified location together with some files generated on the fly. This works great locally, but I read that for distribution via pypi, I have to take care since the files might get zipped.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20885799/4629950) explains how to **access** stuff in the resources (=read them in in python), however, only a single file at a time. What is a secure way to instead copy the folder contents to the specified location?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 'easier' solution is to set `zip_safe=False` in your package setup (`setup.py` or `setup.cfg`), to avoid your package being installed as a zipped egg. Since most installations are done with `pip`, which never creates zipped egg installations, running into a zipped package installation is more rare these days anyway.

You then only have to worry about someone zipping up packages manually into a zipfile to add to `sys.path`, a use case you could choose to not support. That's a different form of zipped packages; eggs are zipfiles for one installable project (supported by `pkg_resources`) and storing them in a directory that's listed on `sys.path`. `pkg_resources` can only support the latter, not the former.

If you do want to support a zipped egg, then for your specific case, it'll be easier to use the [`pkg_resources` API for resource extraction](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#resource-extraction), because while it may be 'slower', it also supports full directory trees. From the `resource_filename()` documentation:

> If the named resource is a directory, then all resources within that directory (including subdirectories) are also extracted.

I'd use it like this:

```
try:
    www_location = pkg_resources.resource_filename("dv", "www_folder")
    shutil.copytree(www_location, dir_path)
finally:
    pkg_resources.cleanup_resources()
```

Resources inside packages found in a zipfile directly added to `sys.path` can't be accessed via `pkg_resources`. For that you need the newer [`importlib.resources` module](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/importlib.html#module-importlib.resources) (or it's [backport](https://importlib-resources.readthedocs.io/)), but this API doesn't support arbitrary directory structures. The [`importlib.resources.path()` function documenation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/importlib.html#importlib.resources.path) states:

> *package* is either a name or a module object which conforms to the `Package` requirements. *resource* is the name of the resource to open within package; it may not contain path separators and it may not have sub-resources (i.e. **it cannot be a directory**).

(bold emphasis mine).

While you can find directories within a package by using [`importlib.resources.contents()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/importlib.html#importlib.resources.contents), you can't actually access the contents of those directories unless they are themselves Python packages (so have a `__init__.py` file in them). The *implementation* of those functions for traditional, non-zipped packages will still give you access to the directory when using `importlib.resources.path()`, you can't do the same when the package is contained in a `.zip` archive.

`importlib.resources` is a better, future proof path to support. To support that you could zip up the `www_folder` resource tree *in your source and wheel distributions*, and then use `with importlib.resources.path("dv", "www_folder.zip") as www_location: www_zip = zipfile.open(www_location)` and extract the contents from that zipfile object to the destination.

Comment: Thank you for the extensive post - I have decided to go with `zip_safe=False` since in this case, the resource files are a mere 60kb and compressing them is really not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in [an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77130809/2748899), Python 3.12+'s standard library allows accessing (possibly by extracting to a temporary location, if the package is zipped) whole directory resources via [`importlib.resources.files`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/importlib.resources.html#importlib.resources.files) and [`importlib.resources.as_file`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/importlib.resources.html#importlib.resources.as_file):

```py
import shutil
from importlib import resources

traversable = resources.files("package.resources")
with resources.as_file(traversable) as path:
    shutil.copytree(path, your_destination_here)

# note: after exiting the `with` block, we can't rely on
# the directory being at `path` anymore!
```

As I also pointed out in my other answer, `importlib.resources` should normally be preferred over `pkg_resources`, because [the latter is deprecated](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html) in favor of the former.