# find data files inside a Python package - setup.py's package_data={...} maybe broken?

Tags: python, build, python-packaging

I have the same situation like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/779495/6597765), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6028000/6597765), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62926517/6597765), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11848030/6597765). I followed the advice given in those questions and I still get the FileNotFoundError.

--tree--

```
.
MANIFEST.in
setup.py
...
--src
   |--__init__.py
   |--mypkg
        |--__init__.py
        |--module_1.py  # dosth_1() in module_1  needs somedata.json
        ...
   |--data
        |--__init__.py
        |--somedata.json
        |--someotherdata.txt
        ...
```

--setup.py--

```
packages=["mypkg"],
package_dir={"": "src"},
package_data={"mypkg": ["data/*.txt", "data/*.json"]},
```

--after removing the old build--

```
(venv)$ python3 -m build
...
copying src/mypkg/somedata.json -> .../src/mypkg/data
...
adding 'mypkg/data/somedata.json'
...
```

--next--

- upload the mypkg to PyPI
- pip install mypkg (within a different vEnv)

--open python interpreter--

```
>>from mypkg import module_1
>>res = module_1.dosth_1()
```

--throws error--

> ... File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/resources.py", line 82, in
> _check_location
> raise FileNotFoundError(f'Package has no location {package!r}') FileNotFoundError: Package has no location <module 'mypkg.data'
> (namespace)>

So I'm really confused why this happens. I took care of the **init**.py, I did the setup.py as advertised, and if I understand the build comments correctly the data file is added to the build. Still the installed package has no access to the data. What's wrong here?

Comment: Did the data files actually get installed with `pip`? I.e., are they in `site-packages/mypkg/data`?

Comment: @MattDMo Yes, I can see all of them.

Comment: `pip build` makes a .tar.gz file, you can open it in standard archive tools to see what's inside. `pip wheel` makes a wheel file which is a zip file, again, archive tools can inspect it, but you may need to change the extension.

Answer (score 3):

Solved it by changing the setup.py from:

```
packages=["mypkg"],
package_dir={"": "src"},
package_data={"mypkg": ["data/*.txt", "data/*.json"]},
```

to:

```
packages=["mypkg"],
include_package_data=True,
package_dir={"": "src"},
```

To me this seems obscure. It actually makes me wonder if the package_data={...} is maybe broken.