# How to load resources file without giving entire path in Python

Tags: python

I want to read the `properties` file in Python without giving the entire path. Because if my code is deployed somewhere else then my package would fail if I pass the hardcore value. So below is my code to read the properties file by giving the entire path:

```
import configparser
config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
config.read('C:\\Users\\s\\IdeaProjects\\PysparkETL\\src\\main\\resources\\configs.properties')
dbname = config['DB']['dbname']
username=config['DB']['user']
password=config['DB']['password']
table=config['DB']['tablename']
driver=config['DB']['driver']
print(dbname)
```

and below is my `configs.properties` file:

```
[DB]
dbname=ourdb
user=root
password=root
tablename=loadtable
driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

I tried different ways like `ConfigParser` instead of `RawConfigParser` but didn't work. Is there any way to load files from the classpath?
Also, I tried different ways from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028000/how-to-read-a-static-file-from-inside-a-python-package) link but it didn't help. All I need is a path to pass it to `config.read` method but it should not be hardcoded as I did it in the code.

Below is my project structure:

[image]

Also, as suggested I tried below code and passed the URL to the config.read method but it's not working.

```
props = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname("resources"),  # folder where the python file is
    'src/main/resources/configs.properties'
)
config.read(props)
```

I get below error:

```
   raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'DB'
```

Comment: Use relative path?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a (static) file from inside a Python package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028000/how-to-read-a-static-file-from-inside-a-python-package)

Comment: I think I tried it too.. but let me do it again.

Comment: I tried `pkgutil` and `importlib_resources` packages but it didn't work for me..What I need is to get the path of the file to be read so that I can pass it to the `config.read` method

Comment: It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

if the file will always be in the same place relative to your python file, you can do the following:

```
props = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__name__),  # folder where the python file is
    'relative/path/to/configs.properties'
)
```

Comment: what is the relative path over here? Is it ok if i just pass the file name and it can get the file path for me?

Comment: I have edited my question as per your suggestion. Could you please have a glance once?