# Accessing installed non-python files in cli program?

Tags: setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging, python-importlib

I am trying to package a console program that I've written in python that has some non-python xslt files.

This is what my package directory looks like:

```
fpds-converter
|   debug.log
|   MANIFEST.in
|   requirements-dev.txt
|   requirements.txt
|   setup.py
\---converter
|   |   fpds_conversion.py
|   |   __init__.py
|   \---xlst
|   |   |    normalize-record.xsl
\---scripts
|   |   __init__.py
|   |   cli.py
```

My cli program is a cli program run by `fpds`; however when I run `fpds args ...` I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\projects\fpds-converter\.venv\Scripts\fpds-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('fpds-converter==1.0.0', 'console_scripts', 'fpds')()
  File "d:\projects\fpds-converter\.venv\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 489, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "d:\projects\fpds-converter\.venv\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2852, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "d:\projects\fpds-converter\.venv\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2443, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "d:\projects\fpds-converter\.venv\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2449, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "d:\projects\fpds-converter\.venv\lib\site-packages\scripts\cli.py", line 4, in <module>
    from converter.fpds_conversion import parse
  File "d:\projects\fpds-converter\.venv\lib\site-packages\converter\fpds_conversion.py", line 9, in <module>
    with open("xslt/normalize-record.xsl", 'rb') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'xslt/normalize-record.xsl'
```

Inside my converter\fpds_converions.py

```
with open("xslt/normalize-record.xsl", 'rb') as f:
    transform = et.XSLT(et.fromstring(f.read()))
```

In `.venv\Lib\site-packages\converter\xslt` I see my `normalize-record.xsl` file.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Using a relative path may lead to the wrong directory as it is based on current working directory. You can use the module's `__file__` attribute as base for constructing the path.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a (static) file from inside a Python package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028000/how-to-read-a-static-file-from-inside-a-python-package)

Comment: Do not use `__file__`. This is straight bad advice. Use `importlib.resources` on Python _3.7+_ and `importlib-metadata` on other versions, or `pkgutil.get_data()`. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58941536/11138259).

Comment: I went the `pkgutil.get_data()` route.