# How can I install a directory in a python module?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, setup.py

I am writing a python module and need to install a directory along with the module. This is what my file tree looks like:

```
├── module
│   └── temp
│   |   └── __init.py__
|   |       file2.yaml
|   |       file.yaml
│   └── module.py
|       __init__.py
├── setup.py
```

As you can see, `module.py` is the main module with all my functions, but it needs to access what is in the `temp` directory. When I use setup tools to install my module locally, using pip, it installs the `module.py` perfectly, but it won't install the `temp` directory.

Here is my `setup.py`:

```
setup(name='module',
      packages=find_packages(),
      version=VERSION,
      description=DESCRIPTION,
      long_description=LONG_DESCRIPTION,
      license=LICENSE,
      author=AUTHORS,
      install_requires=[
          ],
      include_package_data=False
      )
```

My theory is that I need to pass something through `find packages()`.

Side note:
I am running `setup.py` as `python setup.py bdist_wheel`. To clarify, everything is working fine, my directory is just not being installed with the package.

When I go to where the package is stored, `__init__.py` and `module.py` are the only things that are installed in my `module` package directory.

How can I make sure that the `temp` directory is installed as well?

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:
My first file tree was wrong. The `temp` directory is inside the directory with the module.

Comment: See [How to read a (static) file from inside a Python package?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6028000/674039)

Comment: That’s exactly what the other question describes how to do. Follow the instructions. I can see you didn’t follow those instructions because you have include_package_data=False.

Comment: Thank you wim, you pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

When python install packages, the module directory will be copied to the directory like `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/module`. If you add the extra tmp directory, it may conflict with other module.
How about considering moving the tmp directory to the module directory. like this:

```
├── module
│   └── temp
│   |   └── __init.py__
|   |       file2.yaml
|   |       file.yaml
│   └── module.py
|       __init__.py
├── setup.py
```

Comment: So sorry, my directory actually looks like that, I will update it. So to clarify, my directory looks like that, but I am still having the issue.

Comment: Since  you changed your question and moved the tmp directory to module directory. My Answer no longer fit your question. Like wim commented, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028000/how-to-read-a-static-file-from-inside-a-python-package is what your are looking for.

Comment: I saw this feed, but it doesn't answer my question. I just need to install the temp directory along with everything else I install when I install my module.