# Right way to access files from other folders

Tags: python, relative-path, absolute-path

I started moving parts of code outside my jupyter notebooks. I am new in Python and want to make everything right from the beginning. I have a following project structure.

[image: folder structure]

Using `data/raw/filename` obviously doesn't work, I have to go one level up. Like:

```
with open ('../data/dumps/df_aggregated.dmp', 'rb') as fp:
    df_aggregated = pickle.load(fp)
```

I think I can save my absolute path to `data` somewhere in a python script, but I have some doubts if it is right. What if I execute a script/a notebook from a nested folder?

Please help me to understand how to arrange my folders and make it *flexible*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a (static) file from inside a Python package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028000/how-to-read-a-static-file-from-inside-a-python-package)

Comment: @jordanm sorry, I don't understand how to apply it in my case. Could you explain it more? I don't include data in packages.