# Using Resources Module to Import Data Files

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Background**

I have a function called `get_player_call_logic_df` which basically reads a csv file from the `PLAYER_TEST_INPUT` path. I have a module called `player_test` and inside that i have another folder called `player_test_input` where i store all the `csv` files that are used for processing.

**Code**

```
PLAYER_TEST_INPUT_DIR = Path("../dev/playerassignment/src/player/player/player_test/player_test_input/")
def get_player_call_logic_df() -> pd.DataFrame:
    df = pd.read_csv(
       PLAYER_TEST_INPUT_DIR / "player_call_logic.csv"
    )
    return df
```

**Issue**

I created a PR and I got a very good suggestion that I  look at the [importlib.resources](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib.resources) module. You can store the data as a "resource" in the library. Then, instead of referring to the data via filepath, you can import it similar to any other `player` module.

I am unsure how i would use `resources` module here. I read up on the doc and here is what i could come up with. I can probably do something like this.

```
from importlib import resources
def get_player_call_logic_df() -> pd.DataFrame:
    with resources.path("player.player_test_input", "player_call_logic.csv") as df:
        return df
```

I feel like i am doing the same thing so i am not sure how to use the resources module correctly. Any help would be appreciated as i am new to python.

Comment: This is basically doing the same thing, except the latter always works! You used a relative path in the first code and that is relative to the current working directory, which could be anything. OTOH, `importlib` know exactly where that package is, so it does not rely on CWD being anything specific.

Answer (score 1):

Please use

```
from importlib import resources
import pandas as pd

def get_player_call_logic_df() -> pd.DataFrame::
    with resources.path("player.player_test_input", "player_call_logic.csv") as df:
        return pd.read_csv(df)
```

and bear in mind the `__init__.py` file inside the `player_test_input` folder:

```
.
└── player
    ├── __init__.py
    └── player_test_input
        ├── __init__.py
        └── player_call_logic.csv
```

Very good reference and alternatives can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028000/how-to-read-a-static-file-from-inside-a-python-package) and [here](https://github.com/wimglenn/resources-example)