# pkg_resources.ModuleNotFoundError extra resources

Tags: python

I have a Python package that has some template files. I'm trying to access the path to them using `pkg_resources`, but I can't figure out how:

`antigravity.py`:

```py
import pkg_resources

def my_function():
    print(pkg_resources.resource_listdir('antigravity', 'extras'))
    print(pkg_resources.resource_filename('antigravity', 'foo.dat'))
    print(pkg_resources.resource_filename('antigravity.extras', 'bar.dat'))
    return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_function()
```

The output is:

```
python antigravity\antigravity.py
['bar.dat', 'test.txt']
C:\git\swt_root\new_project\antigravity\foo.dat
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "antigravity\antigravity.py", line 22, in <module>
    my_function()
  File "antigravity\antigravity.py", line 16, in my_function
    print(pkg_resources.resource_filename('antigravity.extras', 'bar.dat'))
  File "C:\Users\my_user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1128, in resource_filename
    return get_provider(package_or_requirement).get_resource_filename(
  File "C:\Users\my_user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 345, in get_provider
    __import__(moduleOrReq)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'antigravity.extras'; 'antigravity' is not a package
```

I'm not trying to read `bar.dat`, I'm actually trying to replace the following code:

```
import pathlib

script_folder = pathlib.Path(__file__).parents[0]
bar = script_folder.joinpath('extras', 'bar.dat')
```

I've installed the package with `pip install -e .`. I'm using Anaconda on Windows 10.

My package structure is:

```
new_project
|   MANIFEST.in
|   setup.py
|
\---antigravity
    |   antigravity.py
    |   foo.dat
    |   __init__.py
    |
    \---extras
            bar.dat
            __init__.py
```

`MANIFEST.in`:

```
include antigravity/foo.dat
include antigravity/extras/bar.dat
```

`setup.py`:

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name="antigravity",
    version="0.0.1",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    test_suite="test",
    python_requires=">=3.6",
)
```

`__init__.py`:

```
from .antigravity import my_function
```

`foo.dat:`

```
foo
```

`bar.dat:`

```
bar
```

Comment: Try `pkg_resources.resource_string('antigravity', 'extras/bar.dat')`.  Personally I don't recommend to use `pkg_resources`, though, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58941536/674039) for my recommendations.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear: I'm actually trying to get `bar.dat` path.

Comment: Are you sure `antigravity/extras` includes a `__init__.py` file as well?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy It's not usual for resource subdirectories to contain an `__init__.py`.  They are not subpackages.

Comment: @Leonardo Why do you want to get a path? It is not actually required for package resources to even have a path on the filesystem (e.g. zipfile packaging, dynamically generated resources)

Comment: @wim, the `extras` folder contains a bunch of Mustache templates and partials, I need to pass that path to Mustache: `pystache.Renderer(search_dirs=base_template)`, with `base_template` being the path to my `extras` folder.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy, I created an `extras/__init__.py` file, `print(pkg_resources.resource_filename('antigravity.extras', 'bar.dat'))` breaks, `print(pkg_resources.resource_filename('antigravity', 'extras/bar.dat'))` works though.

Comment: You should not add the `__init__.py` file into resource directories. It is neither required nor desirable.

Comment: @Leonardo Could you clarify, what do you know, the filename `bar.dat` or the resource subdir name `extras`? Both? Neither? You say you're trying to get `bar.dat` path but that may not be unique, a package could have two `bar.dat` resources in different subpaths.

Comment: @wim, I'm very sorry for not being clear. I've edited the question, and what I really need to know is if there's a better alternative to `pathlib.Path(__file__).parents[0]`, like using `pkg_resources`. If there isn't, that's fine.

Comment: Yes, there is a better alternative - have a read over https://importlib-resources.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html#file-system-or-zip-file