# Include template files in poetry project

Tags: python, python-poetry

I have a command line python app using poetry, that I would like to ship with a couple of jinja2 template files. As of know I have them in a `template` directory. How would I go about shipping those templates with the app and how do I make sure that the app knows where the templates are located?

Here's my (naive) attempt at using pkgutil to accomplish this:

directory structure:

```
.
├── app.py
├── LICENSE
├── poetry.lock
├── pyproject.toml
└── templates
    └── message.en_US.jinja2
```

app.py:

```py
import pkgutil
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader

data = pkgutil.get_data(__name__, "templates")

env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader(data))
template = env.get_template("message.en_US.jinja2")
print(template.render({"foo": 1, "bar": 2}))
```

pyproject.toml:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "app"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "Does stuff"
authors = ["Foo Bar <foo@bar.com>"]
license = "AGPL-3.0-or-later"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.8"
jinja2 = "^2.11.3"

[tool.poetry.scripts]
app = "app:main"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry>=0.12"]
build-backend = "poetry.masonry.api"
```

This fails because the templates folder doesn't get packaged. I also don't know if I can pass the folder to the `Environment` constructor like this.

Comment: Show your project directory structure and your `pyproject.toml`. In common cases poetry automatically adds those (see [packages](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#packages) and [include and exclude](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#include-and-exclude)). -- To read the templates at run-time use [pkgutil](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pkgutil.html) or [importlib.resources](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib.resources), and read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58941536/11138259).

Comment: I see your edit and looks good, but you still need to add `templates` as a package, so you would need to use `include` or `packages` as documented.

Comment: pkgutil doesn't accept it when you instruct it to load a directory. How do I go about marrying pkgutils and Environment?

Comment: I don't know Jinja, but maybe use [_`PackageLoader`_](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/api/?highlight=environment#jinja2.PackageLoader) instead (and probably you don't need pkgutil at all). Also you need to fix your packaging.

Comment: for a start, you could add `include = ["templates/*"]` in your `[tool.poetry]` section, run `poetry build`, and then unzip the resulting `.whl` file to look inside and check whether the templates got packaged or not. If you get that far, you should be able to handle the rest with `importlib.resources`, as sinoroc linked.

Comment: `PackageLoader` is what did it in the end. You have to add an empty `__init__.py` however to turn it into a package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of *Jinja* this can be done easily with [*`PackageLoader`*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/api/#jinja2.PackageLoader), which is able to load resources from a Python import package directly.

And of course make sure the resource files (the template files) are correctly "packaged": the files should be part of an import package. In the case of *poetry*, make sure to have the correct values for the  [*`include`*](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#include-and-exclude) and [*`packages`*](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#packages) fields in your `pyproject.toml`.

Answer (score 2):

Poetry provides a fairly simple but non-obvious solution (tucked away):
[pyproject.toml - [poetry.tool]include = [...]](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#include-and-exclude)

```py
[tool.poetry]
...
include = ["resource/resource.txt"]
```