# Ship Python package with custom matplotlibrc file

Tags: python, matplotlib, package

I am writing a package that, among other things, does some plotting with matplotlib. I'd like all the plots generated using the package to follow a custom style, defined in a `matplorlibrc` file. Currently, I am using a (minimal) package structure as follows:

```
pkg
├── pkg
│   ├── afile.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── _mpl_config
│       └── style.mplstyle
└── setup.py
```

The following is near the top of `afile.py`:

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use(os.path.join(
    os.path.split(__file__)[0], '_mpl_config', 'style.mplstyle'))

# some plotting routines...
```

In `__init__.py`:

```
import pkg.afile
```

After doing a `pip install`, I can use a plotting routine with

```
import pkg
pkg.<plotting_routine>
```

So far this seems to work, as the above line instructs matplotlib to use the style found at `<path_to_pkg>/pkg/_mpl_config/style.mplstyle`. However, I'm not sure if this is robust enough (i.e. will be used in all import cases) or if there is a better way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a (static) file from inside a Python package?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20885799/3279716) See the second example in that answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should not overwrite the matplotlib style with your package, because the end user may want to use its own style in other parts of its code. Instead, use a context manager each time you want to make a plot:

```py
with mpl.style.context(os.path.join(os.path.split(__file__)[0], '_mpl_config', 'style.mplstyle')):
    # Do your plotting here
```