# loading data from folder inside package

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle, python-packaging, joblib

I have some `.pkl` files inside a folder (say `data_pkl`) in a package(pip installable) and I want to load these files in some `.py` outside package. However, I'm unsure on following

1. should I write `MANIFEST.in` file
2. are there any changes that has to be made in the `setup.py` file
3. do I need to put `__init__.py` inside the `data_pkl` folder
4. how can I import the .pkl files inside a python script using the package.

EDIT:
`include_package_data=True` in `setup.py`.

If set to True, this tells setuptools to automatically include any data files it finds inside your package directories, that are either under CVS or Subversion control, or which are specified by your MANIFEST.in file. This answers 1 and 2.

Comment: To read "package data", use [_`importlib.resources`_](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib.resources) or [_`pkgutil`_](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.get_data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.pkl` data are probably serialized data using [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) python module. It can't be imported. You have to deserialize data.

```py
import pickle
data = pickle.load(open("data.pkl", "rb"))
```

As say in other answer, you can wraps this in a python module.

```py
# filename: data.py
import pickle

def load_data(filename):
    return pickle.load(open(filename, "rb"))
```

If your `.pkl` files are in a python package, you can retreive its using [`pkg_resources`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html).

```py
import pickle
import pkg_resources

def load_data(resource_name):
    return pickle.load(
        pkg_resources.resource_stream("my_package", resource_name))
```

In python >= 3.7, data can be retreived using [`importlib.resources`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib.resources) to prevent use of thrird-party package.

```py
data = pickle.load(
    importlib.resources.open_binary("my_package.data_folder", "data.pkl"))
```

Comment: No need to rely on `pkg_resources` which is part of a 3rd party library (_setuptools_), when the same functionality is available in the standard library, in `importlib.resources` or `pkgutil`.

Comment: That's right, but only for python >= 3.7.

Comment: [_`pkgutil.get_data()`_](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.get_data) seems compatible with everything. See: https://github.com/wimglenn/resources-example and https://stackoverflow.com/a/58941536

Comment: @sinoroc second resource was also very useful to me.