# How do I refer to a json file that s inside a python package by a file that is also inside the same package

Tags: python-3.x, setup.py

I created a Python package with a structure as follows:

```
pkg_dir
   -mypkg
       -folder1
           -_init_.py
           -do_calc_.py
       -folder2
           -_init_.py
           -my.json
.
.
.
setup.py
```

Inside the `folder1/do_calc.py`, I need to read the `my.json` file from `folder2` and use it in `folder1/do_calc.py`.

I am importing this `mypkg` into another Python script, and I am calling the `do_calc` function.   However, the script is failing because inside `mypkg`, this read statement in `folder1/do_calc.py`:

```
with open('../folder2/my.json') as f:
    jsn = json.load(f)
```

is failing; because it seems that `../` path refers to the Python script where `mypkg` is imported; and not `mypkg`  relative path.

please advise with a simple example, how to set up a path inside the `mypkg` so that I can pass `my.json` to

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a (static) file from inside a Python package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028000/how-to-read-a-static-file-from-inside-a-python-package)

Answer (score -1):

I figured this one out and I hope by posting her,  it may provide answer to folks who may run into same issue in the future.  What I did is as follows:

```
filepath = resource_filename('mypkg', 'folder2/my.json')
with open(filepath, 'r') as my_jsn:
...
```

This allowed me to, inside the pkg, read a json file that I can use  somewhere else inside the same pkg.

Comment: Use [_`pkgutil.get_data(...)`_](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.get_data) or [_`importlib.resources`_](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib.resources). See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58941536).