# load_dotenv fails when running from a package

Tags: python, python-packaging

Using `load_dotenv` to read python variables from a .env file.
Building a python package using the `setup` module and packaging it into a command `get_values`

Cases when code runs successfully

1- Codebase runs and I can read the environment values only if the command 'get_values' is running from the same directory as codebase.

2- Codebase runs as a standalone Python program

Cases, when code doesn't, runs successfully

1- After building the package, I run the commands 'get_values' the code fails to read the environment variables and get the string value as NoneType

Current Codebase hierarchy:

[image]
.env file

```
OIDC_CLIENT_ID='xxxxxxxxxxx'
```

Code to read environment file

```
 basepath = Path()
 basedir = str(basepath.cwd())
 envars = basepath.cwd() / 'config.env'
 load_dotenv(envars)
```

Reading the environment variable

```
  print(os.getenv('OIDC_CLIENT_ID'))
```

Comment: what does the output of `import sys; print(sys.path)` say in the failing case?

Comment: In either cases, getting bunch of *.egg files 

['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python37.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aaaaa-1.0-py3.7.egg',

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a (static) file from inside a Python package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028000/how-to-read-a-static-file-from-inside-a-python-package)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your current working directory contains a 'config.env' file in the cases where it's not working.

Comment: Idea is to create a package that can be used from anywhere

Comment: You probably shouldn't include the .env file which include credentials in the package. It is better to provide the credential at runtime.