# Why use importlib.resources over __file__?

Tags: python, resources

I have a package which is like

```
mypkg
    |-mypkg
        |- data
            |- data.csv
            |- __init__.py  # Required for importlib.resources 
        |- scripts
            |- module.py
        |- __init__.py
```

The module `module.py` requires `data.csv` to perform a certain task.

The first naive approach I used to access `data.csv` was

```
# module.py - Approach 1
from pathlib import Path

data_path = Path(Path.cwd().parent, 'data', 'data.csv')
```

but this obviously breaks when we have imported `module.py` via `from mypkg.scripts import module` or similar. I need a way to access `data.csv` regardless of where `mypkg` is imported from.

The next naive approach is to use `__file__` attribute to get access to the path wherever the `module.py` module is located.

```
# module.py - Approach 2
from pathlib import Path

data_path = Path(Path(__file__).resolve().parents[1], 'data', 'data.csv')
```

However, researching around about this problem I find that this approach is discouraged. See, for example, [How to read a (static) file from inside a Python package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028000/how-to-read-a-static-file-from-inside-a-python-package?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Though there doesn't seem to be total agreement as to the best solution to this problem, it looks like `importlib.resources` is maybe the most popular. I believe this would look like:

```
# module.py - Approach 3
from pathlib import Path
import importlib.resources

data_path_resource = importlib.resources('mypkg.data', 'data.csv')
with data_path_resources as resource:
    data_path = resource
```

Why is this final approach better than `__file__`? It seems like `__file__` won't work if the source code is zipped. This is the case I'm not familiar with and which also sounds a bit fringe. I don't think my code will ever be run zipped..

The added overhead from `importlib` seems a little ridiculous. I need to add an empty `__init__.py` in the data folder, I need to import `importlib`, and I need to use a context manager just to access a relative path.

What am I missing about the benefits of the `importlib` strategy? Why not just use `__file__`?

edit: One possible justification for the `importlib` approach is that it has slightly improved semantics. That is `data.csv` should be thought of as part of the package, so we should access it using something like `from mypkg import data.csv` but of course this syntax only works for importing `.py` python modules. But `importlib.resources` is sort of porting the "import something from some package" semantics to more general file types.

By contrast, the syntax of building a relative path from `__file__` is sort of saying: this module is incidentally close to the data file in the file structure so let's take advantage of that to access it. The fact that the data file is part of the package isn't leveraged.

Comment: Did you read [wim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58941536/8601760)? It's the top answer sorted by "Trending (recent votes count more)". It discusses why not to use either of those you mentioned. It recommends `pkgutil`, and `importlib_resources` for Python 3.9+, instead.

Comment: @aaron I want to understand the top answers in the linked question better. (1) what are more details about the zip/wheel thing? When might that use case occur and what does it look like in detail? (2) in the approaches in the linked answer I want to know how I can get a path to resources so I can open *whatever* type of binary file I have using whatever helper module (csv, h5 etc.), not just opening as a binary.

Comment: I asked this questions on python discourse: https://discuss.python.org/t/easy-and-recommended-way-to-get-path-of-datafile-within-package/20581/8 The conclusion there was that `__file__` is fine for most applications and it's easy to understand, so I should just use it if it works. If I ever get involved with zip apps I guess I'll need to learn more about the other approaches.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use something like this with `__file__`:

```
import csv
from io import StringIO
from pathlib import Path
import pkgutil
import sys


def main():
    # Point to appropriate ancestor directory
    p = Path(__file__).parent.parent.parent
    sys.path.insert(0, str(p))
    data = pkgutil.get_data('mypkg.data', 'data.csv')
    reader = csv.reader(StringIO(data.decode()))
    for row in reader:
        print(row)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If the file `data.csv` contains

```
Col 1,Col 2
v1,v2
```

then the above script will print

```
['Col 1', 'Col 2']
['v1', 'v2']
```

You can see the whole thing running [here](https://replit.com/join/qnsnssmrfs-vsajip) if you select the "Shell" tab and run `python mypkg/scripts/module.py`.